# How to get the Android Advertising ID or iOS IDFA through a mobile website?

Tags: android, ios, ads, idfa, google-advertising-id

I've been googling this for a while and can not find a definitive answer.

AAID or IDFA is the key of publisher monetization. Without it, publishers have to fall back to the old-fashion cookie matching, which is inefficient (in terms of latency and bandwidth usage) and inefficient (in terms of dataset, since mobile user behavior is mostly associated with AAID/IDFA now, instead of cookies)

One can expect that the default browser in Android/iOS (Chrome/Safari) should provide some Javascript interface for web pages to retrieve this crucial (for publisher) and insensitive (for user) ID. However, I failed to find such thing. Maybe they're pushing developers to native mobile app development.

So, is there any way that I can get AAID/IDFA in web pages? Or is there any other way I can associate the visitor with AAID/IDFA?

Comment: The IDFA is only available to native apps on iOS and I am not sure why you think that user's won't care about being tracked

Comment: @Paulw11 , Thanks for the iOS info. And, I don't think that users won't care about being tracked. But AAID/IDFA is designed to be anonymous and opt-out-able, which is insensitive enough.

Comment: @Paulw11 "The IDFA is only available to native apps on iOS" -- Do you have a source for this? It seems ridiculous to me that this information would not be accessible outside of iOS applications.